# converting pandas dataframe into series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have following dataframe.

```
   order_id   Clusters
0    519     Cluster 5
1    520     Cluster 1
2    521     Cluster 1
3    523     Cluster 5
4    524     Cluster 1
5    525     Cluster 4
6    526     Cluster 4
7    527     Cluster 1
8    528     Cluster 2
9    529     Cluster 5
10   530     Cluster 6
11   531     Cluster 3
12   532     Cluster 1
13   533     Cluster 4
14   534     Cluster 5
15   535     Cluster 5
```

I want following series out of above dataframe.

```
Cluster 1   [520 ,521, 524, 527, 532]
Cluster 2   [528]
Cluster 3   [531]
Cluster 4   [525,526,533]
Cluster 5   [519,523,529,534,535]
Cluster 6   [530]
```

This is my approach in python.

```
clusters_order_id = []

df_clusters = df.groupby('Clusters')

for i in df_clusters['order_id']:
   clusters_order_id.append(i)
```

which gives me

```
clusters_order_id
Out[196]: 
0    (Cluster 1, [520, 521, 524, 527, 532])
1                        (Cluster 2, [528])
2                        (Cluster 3, [531])
3              (Cluster 4, [525, 526, 533])
4    (Cluster 5, [519, 523, 529, 534, 535])
5                        (Cluster 6, [530])
```

But I am not getting how to seperate above into series of above form. So that Cluster 1,Cluster 2 will become my index and corresponding order ids will be an array. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print df.groupby('Clusters')['order_id'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())

Clusters
Cluster 1    [520, 521, 524, 527, 532]
Cluster 2                        [528]
Cluster 3                        [531]
Cluster 4              [525, 526, 533]
Cluster 5    [519, 523, 529, 534, 535]
Cluster 6                        [530]
Name: order_id, dtype: object
```

Timing:

```
In [153]: %timeit df.groupby('Clusters')['order_id'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
1000 loops, best of 3: 751 µs per loop

In [154]: %timeit df.pivot_table(index='Clusters', aggfunc=pd.Series.tolist)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.55 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj5m_W-tKnKAhWCEHIKHQP6ASkQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fversion%2F0.17.1%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.pivot_table.html&usg=AFQjCNEfEBvbGcha0eG6ByK5ODKZkK-_hw&bvm=bv.111677986,d.bGQ):

```
In [473]: df.pivot_table(index='Clusters', aggfunc=pd.Series.tolist)
Out[473]:
                            order_id
Clusters
Cluster 1  [520, 521, 524, 527, 532]
Cluster 2                      [528]
Cluster 3                      [531]
Cluster 4            [525, 526, 533]
Cluster 5  [519, 523, 529, 534, 535]
Cluster 6                      [530]
```